# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'location.pathname'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router

I have this `Feed` component. The idea is to preserve scroll on multiple feeds (tabs), e.g. I'm on `"localhost/feed-one"`, I scroll to 500px, switch to `"localhost/feed-two"`, and when I return to feed 1, the scroll should be back on 500px. The following code works as expected, yet ESLint shows a warning and I want to fix it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loader from '../Loader/Loader';
import Post from '../Post/Post';
import Data, { Post as PostType } from '../../emulateAPI/Data';
import useScrollRestoration from '../../hooks/useScrollRestoration';
import './Feed.scss';

interface FeedProps {
  data: Data;
}

const Feed: React.FC<FeedProps> = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  const { categorySlug } = useParams<string>();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>();
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<PostType[]>([]);
  const location = useLocation();
  const reScroll = useScrollRestoration();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const category = data.getCategoryBySlug(categorySlug);
    if (category) {
      setPosts(data.getPostsByCategory(category));
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [categorySlug, data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    reScroll();
  }, [posts]); //I GET THE ERROR HERE: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'reScroll'.

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div className='feed'>
          {posts.map((post, index) => (
            <Post key={index} post={post} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```

My custom hook `useScrollRestoration`:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const useScrollRestoration = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      sessionStorage.setItem(location.pathname, window.scrollY.toString());
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    };
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return (() => {
    const scrollY = sessionStorage.getItem(location.pathname);
    window.scrollTo(0, +(scrollY || 0));
  });
};

export default useScrollRestoration;
```

The warning is in the Feed component: `"React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'reScroll'. Either include it or remove the dependency array."`
But if I do add `reScroll` in the `useEffect` hook's dependency array, the `useEffect` gets called on `location.pathname` changes when new posts haven't been loaded yet and the scroll is often impossible (e.g. I can't scroll back to 500px because the posts haven't loaded yet, React scrolls to say 250px, posts finally load, but the value is already overwritten to 250px). Can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. It's *just* a linter warning, you can choose to ignore it. Disable the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` linting rule for that line.

   ```js
   useEffect(() => {
     reScroll();
     // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
   }, [posts]);
   ```

   Keep in mind that in doing this you are turning off a development tool meant to help you. If the logic of the this effect changes, e.g. the dependencies change, this will not alert you to newly-missing dependencies. In other words, use only if you know what you are doing and at your own risk.
2. Memoize the `rescroll` callback handler so it is a stable reference and can be safely added to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array.

   ```js
   import { useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
   import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

   const useScrollRestoration = () => {
     const { pathname } = useLocation();

     const pathnameRef = useRef(pathname);

     useEffect(() => {
       const onScroll = () => {
         sessionStorage.setItem(pathnameRef.current, window.scrollY.toString());
       };

       window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

       return () => {
         window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
       };
     }, []);

     const reScroll = useCallback(() => {
       const scrollY = sessionStorage.getItem(pathnameRef.current);
       window.scrollTo(0, +(scrollY || 0));
     }, []);

     return reScroll;
   };

   export default useScrollRestoration;
   ```

   ```js
   const Feed: React.FC<FeedProps> = (props) => {
     ...
     const reScroll = useScrollRestoration();

     ...

     useEffect(() => {
       reScroll();
     }, [posts, reScroll]);

     ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can only call the `rescroll` when you have posts loaded like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!posts.length) return;
  reScroll();
}, [posts, reScroll]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but there already are some posts when this useEffect executes, say I switch from Feed 2 with 20 posts to Feed 1, location.pathname changes but posts state not yet

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with using refs. I only want to call `reScroll()` when user has already switched feeds and all the relevant posts have been loaded, not just when `location.pathname` changes. So there's a need to indicate that the posts have been loaded, and setting state won't help because it won't take immediate effect. Working solution for my use case:

```
    const isRedirecting = useRef<boolean>();

// On url change set a ref to indicate that user is switching feeds, but relevant posts haven't been loaded yet.
    useEffect(() => {
        isRedirecting.current = true;
    }, [location.pathname]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            const category = data.getCategoryBySlug(categorySlug);
            if (category) {
                setPosts(data.getPostsByCategory(category));
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
            isRedirecting.current = false; // Posts are loaded, feed switching done. Now just have to wait for setIsLoading(false) to take effect!
        }, 1000);
    }, [categorySlug, data, favs]);

// Check if necessary state changes have been rendered.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isRedirecting.current) {
            reScroll();
        }
    }, [isLoading, reScroll]);
```

I'm a noob, so let me know what you think.